# how to run django application on browser which is hosted on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have created a website based on Django framework. I want to run that website through the amazon aws. I have already created an instance on aws and downloaded the code from git in the instance.

The problem I am now facing is I am not able to understand how to run the website made through django on the browser. I have read some blogs about using nginx but is there a way to do it just with `wsgi` .

If I directly type the attached ip to the browser with the port, it doesnt show anything. Please help me with the deployment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: WSGI is a specification. You need a server which can talk to Django with WSGI. To do that, you can run a server like Gunicorn or uWSGI to talk to Django and then place it behind nginx or some other webserver to handle static files.

Comment: Grab a cup of coffee. You're going to be here: http://www.nickpolet.com/blog/deploying-django-on-aws/1/ for a while. Or, you could just use Heroku, which is a wrapper for AWS, and is a lot easier to use than configuring everything yourself.

Comment: @Brandon I have gone through the article and tried to implement it as it is.. It isnt working for me.. :(

Comment: Sorry man, AWS can be a complicated beast. At work, I have the luxury of a DevOps team whose sole purpose is to manage our AWS environments. At home, if I want to deploy to AWS, I use Heroku. The cost of running two dynos FAR outweighs the amount of money in time I would be wasting trying to figure out what I did wrong managing the instance(s) myself.

Comment: `isn't working for me` is not right way to ask for help, you need give detail on which part you have issue, what error you get.

Comment: now it is working.. required some modification which i made by reading error logs